# De-duping Object Store in collection

Tags: java, coding-style

**Consider a simple object store with the following interfaces:**

```
// add an object with ‘blob’ content into the system and return an id
int put(string blob); 

// retrieve the contents of an object identified by ‘id’. NULL if doesn’t exist
string get(int); 

// delete an object identified by ‘id’
void delete(int id); 

//number of (non duplicate) objects stored in the object store
int size();
```

**Requirements** 
The object store must de-duplicate objects. Iif the same sequence of bytes is stored twice – then the store must not store the data twice. Objects
can be fairly large – say – ranging in size from 1K to 5MB. Blobs are immutable..
We are looking for standard sequential consistency semantics from these API calls. If an object is ‘put’ – then the next immediate ‘get’ call –
should return the previously put value. E.g. if a client executes the following:

```
Id = objectstore.put(data);
data1 = objectstore.get(id);
```

The second operation must return the same sequence of bytes as that pointed to by ‘data’. No other client/process/thread should be able to
interfere with that.

My code so far:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

public class ObjectStore {

String blobString;
Object objectId;

public ObjectStore(String blobString, Object objectId) {

    this.blobString = blobString;
    this.objectId = objectId;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o){

    if(!(o instanceof ObjectStore)){
        return false;
    }
    if((o == null) || (o.getClass() != this.getClass()))
        return false;
    // object must be Test at this point
    ObjectStore store = (ObjectStore)o;
    return blobString.toString() == store.blobString &&
        (objectId != null && objectId.equals(store.objectId));
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int hash = 7;
    hash = 31 * hash + blobString.hashCode();
    hash = 31 * hash + ((objectId == null) ? 0 : objectId.hashCode());

    return hash;
}

Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();

   /**
   * Put object into store and return id.
   * @param blobString
   * @return
   */
  public int put(String blobString) {
      set.add(blobString);
    return 0;
  }

  /**
   * Get object corresponding to id. Return null if no such object exists.
   * @param objectId
   * @return
   */
  public String get(int objectId) {

    return null;
  }

  /**
   * Release object - don't need it anymore.
   * @param objectId
   */
  public void delete(int objectId) {
    // stub
  }

  /**
   * Number of distinct blobs stored in the objectStore
   * @return
   */
  public int size() {
    // stub
    return 0;
  }

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();


}

}
```

I am unable to identify whatever i need to use Map or Set interface because put() method return object id.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `Map` as you're mapping objects to integer ids. Sets don't necessarily map data, they are just collections with no duplicate elements.

However, as you seem to be writing to an interface the internals of your implementation shouldn't matter. Use what works best, and works with the interface requirement.

Edit 2:

If I were implementing this, I'd use an integer to generate unique ids on `put` operations. This would provide unique ids up to about 4 billion `put` operations.

Also a second map is necessary to check if some blob sequence has been added before. This way you replace old blobs using the same key as the first time.

```
int idProvider=0;
HashMap<Integer, String> map1 = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
HashMap<String, Integer> map2 = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
public int put(String blob){
    int id = -1;
    if(map2.containsKey(blob)){
        id = map2.get(blob);
    }else{
        id = idProvider;
        idProvider+=1;
        map2.put(blob, id);
    }
    map1.put(id, blob);
    return id;
}
public void delete(int id){
    String blob = map1.remove(id);
    if(blob!=null){
        map2.remove(blob);
    }
}
String get(int id){
    String blob = map1.get(id);
    return blob;
}
int size(){
    return map1.size();
}
```

This should meet all the criteria in your question unless thread safety is an issue. If that's the case just synchronize access.  I've compiled, and tested this code.

Test:

```
    ObjectStore store = new ObjectStore();
    int id1 = store.put("hello");
    int id2 = store.put("world");
    int id3 = store.put("world");
    if(store.size()!=2)
        throw new RuntimeException("Wrong size");
    if (id2 != id3)
        throw new RuntimeException("Ids not equal?");
    String strHello = store.get(id1);
    String strWorld = store.get(id3);
    if (!strHello.equals("hello") || !strWorld.equals("world"))
        throw new RuntimeException();
    store.delete(id3);
    String strShouldBeNull = store.get(id3);
    if(strShouldBeNull!=null)
        throw new RuntimeException();
```

Comment: Can you help me how i implement put() method ?

Comment: Sure, I've edited the question to include a full solution give the current problem description. If this will suffice, please accept my answer. If not, let me know.

Comment: While getting value in blob, can we ignore duplicate value by using hash value of hashCode() method. How do i use like return blob.hashCode() ???

Comment: I have used, is it correct ?? 
public String get(Integer objectId) {
     
     int hash = objectId.hashCode();
     String blobString = map.get(hash);
     
     return blobString;
   }

Comment: Hashcodes could work here, but hashcodes can have collision. My code can have collisions too, but only if you put more than 4 billion strings at one time. A hashcode probably would have worked fine, as chances of collision with a hashcode are also small, but this works too.